# How to override language translations in Silverstripe 3?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to override some language translations in a Silverstripe 3 project.

Googling returned this old post referring to Silverstripe 2.x: http://www.ssbits.com/snippets/2009/overriding-silverstripes-language-files-with-your-own/

I used the same method, updated it to the Silverstripe 3 approach, and created the following folders/ files

```
# zlang
+- _config.php
+-#lang
  +- en.yml
```

After a /dev/build and a ?flush=all this has had no effect on changing the text to my translation.

How do I override language translations in Silverstripe 3 without altering the core code?

Comment: You might need to define the priority for the translations to get them loaded in the right order. This page should help you http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/i18n#module-priority haven't tested that my self yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked this out, all I needed to do was add the lang folder to the "project" folder like this:

```
# mysite
+-# lang
  +- en.yml
```

en.yml contains:

```
en:
  ProductForm:
    PRODUCT_ADDED: 'My translation'
    PRODUCT_ADDED_LINK: 'My translation'
    ADD_TO_CART: ''My translation'
```